# Difference between window.title and document.title

Tags: javascript

I am have been reading material on JavaScript and there are two ways of accessing the `title` of the page:

1. The `window.title` property
2. The `document.title` property

But when applying, the second only works. I am unable to understand why there are two titles and why both of them don't work.

Comment: There aren't. `window.title` is not a universal property, whereas `document.title` is. Fire up you're browser's console, and type "window.t" and see what it tries to autocomplete with. There will be no "title" in that list.

Comment: Is `window.title` a depreciated property then?

Comment: `document` is _in_ `window`: `window.document.title` is the same as `document.title`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`window.document.title` is correct.

`window.title` is incorrect, because [the `window` object doesn't have a `title` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) (all the properties of window are down the left side, you'll see `title` isn't there).

Comment: Fair enough, but not terrible for object references

Comment: Fixed it to use MDN